# БутИк или бУтик?

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

Как правильно склонять слово "бутик"? Меня коробит от "бУтико" и "бутикОв"!

Answer (score 1):

БутИк. Это слово французского происхождения, а там все ударения всегда падают на последний слог. И, соответственно, "бутикОв".

Comment: БутиИк - это понятно. А вот почему "бутикОв" - непонятно. 
Если ИК тут было суффиксом еще можно было согласиться - и то с трудом, т.е. суффикс "ИК" в русском ударным не бывает. 
Но тут-то "ИК" вообще часть корня - в русском, естественно, французы нам тут не указ.

Comment: Но  шаблоны  для  похожих  форм  имеются:  тупик - тупиков,  парник -  парников.  Иноязычные  слова  оформляются  по  шаблонам  русского.

Answer (score 1):

БутИк - акцентный класс А (неподвижное ударение на основе в любых формах): бутИк, бутИка и бутИки, бутИков.

Comment: Информация проверена по словарю Резниченко 2004 года

Comment: Извините  за  темноту:  по  каким  признакам  выделяются  акцентные  классы ?

Comment: Существительные делятся на несколько акцентных классов: класс А - это неподвижное ударение на основе во всех формах, класс Б - неподвижное ударение на окончании во всех формах (слеза), остальные классы имеют подвижное ударение, которое переходит с основы на окончание или наоборот для форм единственного и множественного числа.

Answer (score 0):

Как узнать, к какому классу (А,Б или ост.) относится слово?

Comment: И  мне  это  интересно.

Comment: Характеристика акцентных классов существительных дается, например, в Грамматике-80, в словаре Резниченко, но эти книги удобно использовать только как справочники - ПРОГНОЗИРОВАТЬ акцентный класс слова сложно, легче пользоваться готовыми решениями, указанными в словарях. Для справок:Подавляющее количество существительных (около 34000 слов) характеризуется неподвижным ударением. Лишь незначительная часть (около 700 слов) имеет подвижное ударение, но это наиболее употребительные слова.